# Write my research results to/into conference papers?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that I have results from my thesis that I already done with, and now I am working on publishing these results in conference papers. What preposition should I use in the following sentence:

I am currently writing them (results) down *to/into* conference papers

Answer (score 1):

Neither is particularly idiomatic. You already used something close to a better alternative:

> I am currently working on publishing these results as conference papers

Another, taking into account that you cannot guarantee you’ll be successful in publishing, might be:

> I am currently preparing to submit several of these results to conferences

There are many other variations on those themes.